# Why this query uses two table scans?

Tags: sql-server, database-optimization

I have this simple query on SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
SELECT Art.ID_Articulo, 
       conv.Factor AS PesoToneladas 
FROM   dbo.Articulos Art 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.Conversiones conv 
              ON conv.ID_Articulo = Art.ID_Articulo 
                 AND conv.ID_Unidad1 = Art.ID_Unidad
```

Table `Articulos` is indexed individually by `ID_Articulo` and `ID_Unidad`.
Table `Conversiones` is indexed individually by `ID_Articulo` and `ID_Unidad1`.

Execution plans shows **table scan** for both tables taking a lot of resources.

How can I find why?

Comment: You got indexes on the columns you join on?

Comment: We'd need to see both tables scripted out (including indexes).

Comment: From what I know, the optimizer also chooses to do a table scan instead of an index seek (even if there is an index on that column) if the amount of data to be retrieved would be very large (because one "bulk" access of the data would be faster than individually retrieving every row). So, this depends on the amount of data which the query should return..

Comment: How big are your tables?

Comment: Table Articulos is indexed by ID_Articulo(PK) and ID_Unidad individually. Table Conversiones i tried 3 indexes:by ID_Articulo, ID_Unidad1 individually, and ID_Articulo+ID_Unidad1

Comment: Table Articulos has 17700 rows. Table Conversiones has 58498 rows

Comment: Most likely the query optimizer has figured out that you're going to read all the rows of both tables due to the way you have structured foreign keys and the join here, and thus a table scan on each is the best way to go. It probably builds up a hash join or similar as it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no filters in your query, considering this you will aggregate the entire 2 tables. Using indexes sql might need to spend more resources on lookups. So it's probably cheaper to do table scans.

If you will use filters to cut down your data sql might decide to change the plan.

Comment: Could be, but what if he doesn't want to add *more* filters to the query (apart from the ones he already has in the JOIN)?

Comment: Then the 2 scans are probably the best solution to the query. It's probably the fastest / less resource intensive plan. You might be able to make it faster using included columns in indexes .. but that's a waste of disk space and nobody guarantees a faster response.

Comment: Totally agree, I posted a similar comment on the question.

Comment: Thanks. This query takes part of a more complex one and I suppossed that table scan was the problem, but as you mention, if I select the whole tables probably use a table scan is the best solution anyway. The problem was elsewhere. Thanks again.

Comment: @ericpap Take a look at **[this article here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/277/index-scans-and-table-scans/)** to understand more what/when table scans are being used and why it is being used in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks @RaduGheorghiu! Excelent info!

Comment: @ericpap Glad it was helpful!